# Track fill inputs on Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

I would like to track the filling form inputs on my form in Google Analytics.

1. First input is `<select />`, and I added JS code like below:

   $(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'My Form', 'select', 'Choose something...', $('select option:selected').val());
   });
2. Second (and the last) `input` is text, for write something..., I added JS code like below:

   $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'My Form', 'input', 'Write something...', $('input').val());
   });

In GA panel these values are added.

The question are:
1. The third param of `ga` is okey, for grouping?
2. How to show in GA something like paths? "User choose number "5" from `select` and write "text" to `input`?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in the `ga` call would be the event `category` and it looks fine for grouping. Really, you can call it anything you want to so long as it makes sense to those that need to use your reports. However, note that the event value needs to be an integer value. When you say that the value can be "text" that seems to indicate that the event value isn't going necessarily going to be an integer (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#event_fields). If you want to collect strings into the event, and if custom dimensions are not scarce, then you could track text input into the custom dimension. Doing so you can easily pull custom reports and pull in any data from your event. In terms of pathing, you could use the `Behavior Flow` reports to observe pages and associated events.